# Continued fractions paradox

Tags: continued-fractions, fake-proofs

I am preparing to teach an enrichment session to some 16 year olds, about Continued Fractions. I am confused about the following paradox.

> ### 1=2 via Continued Fractions
>
> This is true of course that $1=\frac{2}{3-1}.$ Now, let's substitute this very expression for $1$ in the denominator:
>
> $$1=\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-1}}.$$
>
> We can do that one more time:
>
> $$1=\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-1}}}.$$
>
> And one more time to make sure there is no misunderstanding of the construction,
>
> $$1=\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-1}}}}.$$
>
> At this point I am assuming that further steps could be performed by any reader who got this far. To indicate that possibility I'll use the ellipsis:
>
> $$1=\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\ldots}}}}.$$
>
> Well, we also know that $2=\frac{2}{3-2}.$ With this as a starting point, we follow in the footsteps of the previous example. Replacing $2$ in the denominator with that expression gives
>
> $$2=\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-2}}.$$
>
> To continue as before:
>
> $$2=\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-2}}}}.$$
>
> And finally,
>
> $$2=\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\ldots}}}}.$$
>
> But this is exatly the same continued fraction. By necessity we conclude that $1=2.$
>
> — *by* 24.0.94.225 *at* 20110927 *via [CTK Wiki Math](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/wiki-math/index.php?n=Algebra.12ViaContinuedFractions)*

What is the hole in the argument? Presumably it has something to do with lack of convergence, but would anyone be able to explain it so that:

1. I could undersatnd it (I studied Maths at university)
2. 16 year olds (with no formal knowledge of analysis or the language of convergence) would understand it?

Thank you.

Comment: We generally prefer that questions stand on their own, without making everyone follow your link to find out what is going on.

Comment: Sorry for not spotting the duplication of an earlier question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look very carefully at each and every step, the "paradox" ends up being a "sleight of hand". When it says "I'll use the ellipsis", it means *to indicate that any number of **finite** steps can be performed*. The second time it does not even say "ellipsis", but it means the same. But then, at the end, it says "this is exa[c]tly the same continued fraction". **It is not**. They are *not* continued fractions: they are expressions with finite steps. Continued fractions (as you can see in the other answers) are infinite expressions with some *careful* definition of convergence.

(The sleight of hand is that they *look* the same as the usual form for continued fractions, by using a meaning for ellipsis that is different from the meaning it has in continued fractions.)

[You should really make your question stand alone, by the way.]

Answer (score 15):

When we evaluate a continued fraction, we're trying to *solve an equation*: in this case, $$x={2\over 3-x}.$$

This turns into $3x-x^2=2$, or $x^2-3x+2=0$; or, better yet, $(x-2)(x-1)=0$. This has two solutions, namely $x=2$ and $x=1$.

The "contradiction" here comes from the implicit assumption that a continued fraction *always describes a single number* - in the same way that a decimal expansion picks out a specific real - as opposed to being a description that could apply to several things. Basically, the point is that $$x={2\over 3-{2\over 3-{2\over 3-...}}}$$ is really just a tricky way of saying $$\mbox{"$x$ has the property that $x^2-3x+2=0$,"}$$ which of course doesn't refer uniquely. The expression $${2\over 3-{2\over 3-{2\over 3-...}}}$$ *looks like* something that refers to a specific number, but actually doesn't.

Comment: Thank you! Useful to point out the similarity with quadratic equations - both cases where you might think there is only one solution.

Answer (score 15):

Fundamentally, this is an error where you see something that "looks like" a calculation, and you assume it actually means something. But it doesn't. The expression:

$$\dfrac{2}{3-\dfrac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\dots}}}$$ looks like something, but it isn't well defined. Is it the limit of:

$$\frac{2}{3},\dfrac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3}},\dfrac{2}{3-\dfrac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3}}},\dots$$

or is it the limit of:

$$2,\dfrac{2}{3-2},\dfrac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-2}},\dots?$$

The first sequence converges to $1$, the second sequence converges trivially to $2$ (since every value is $2$.)

It's worth noting that if $x_0$ is defined as any value, and $x_{n+1}=\frac{2}{3-x_n}$, this sequence actually only converges to $2$ if $x_0=2$. This is because:

$$2-\frac{2}{3-x}=\frac{4-2x}{3-x}=\frac{2}{3-x}(2-x)$$

so $|x_{n+1}-2|>|x_n-2|$ when when $x_n>1$ and $x_n\neq 2$. So the only way for it to converge to $2$ is if it is always equal to $2$.

---

You get this problem, too, if you just take a simple equation:

$$x = 1+\frac{1}{1+x}$$

which has solutions $\pm \sqrt{2}$. That seems to mean that the continued fraction:

$$1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\dots}}$$

is likewise ambiguous. The only reason we don't see it as a paradox is that intuitively, we know this is only the positive value.

So the real problem is in extrapolating from the equation $\gamma = a+\frac{b}{c+\gamma}$ to some infinite form, which may ore may not have meaning.

---

A similar error can be seen more simply if you start with:

$$2=1+(-1)+2$$

You would never conclude that $$2=1+(-1)+1+(-1)+\cdots$$

The finite sums always equal $2$, but the $2$ is no longer present in the infinite sum, and you the meaning you ascribe to the infinite sum depends on definitions.

Comment: In your example, the first limit/sequence should start with $1$ so that it trivially goes to $1$ in the same manner the second one does.  :-)

Comment: Yes, but it also converges to one of $x_0=0$ or $x_0=1.9999$. The point is that we get way more cases converging to $1$.

Comment: Ah, okay.  :D My bad

Answer (score 0):

Channeling my inner child for an extremely simple explanation:

The last step states "But this is exatly the same continued fraction." [sic]

They are not the same. One has a 1 in the bottom right. One has a 2 in the bottom right.
The author is using ellipses to elide different things, then claiming the results are equal because they now look the same.

This is like saying

1/3 = 0.33333...

1/3 + 1/3000000 = 0.33333...

therefore 1/3000000 = 0.

from this and the following:

n * 0 = 0

1 * n / n = 0 for n != 0

1 * n = n * 1

we have

3000000 * 1/3000000 = 0

therefore 3000000 * 1/3000000 = 1 * 3000000 / 3000000

therefore 1 * 1 = 0

Comment: "1 * n / n = 0 for n != 0" ??? I understand that you are trying to do a 'fake' proof, so something should be wrong, but in a proper fake proof, the mistake should be hidden so the casual reader misses it...